# What does TXOutDatumHasNone mean when you query utxo?

Tags: cardano-cli

I sent a transaction from Daedalus to my node version 1.30.1 on mainnet and when I query utxo it reads amount* + TXOutDatumHasNone
Are those tokens burned? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TXOutDatumHasNone` means that the specific UTXO does not contain any `Datum`.

As per [docs.cardano.org](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/datums-redeemers):

> The datum is a piece of information that can be associated with a UTXO
> and is used to carry script state information such as its owner or the
> timing details (which define when the UTXO can be spent). It is
> frequently used in combination with a redeemer – which is arbitrary
> information included in a transaction to provide an input to the
> script.

Answer (score 0):

Its like a text you can add to a transaction. And hold information about spending the asset too, can be use with a script too.